# please explain javascript called on form element

Tags: javascript

Please explain this code

```
"<form action='' onkeypress =if ( event.keyCode == 13){ 
 $(&#39;#validate&#39;).click(); return false; }>"
```

this event is called on form element

Comment: If they press enter/return it will execute the click event on the $("validate") element.

Comment: It seems a sort of trying to make "Return" (keycode 13) to simulate click on a element. The $ function is a jQuery shortcut...

Answer (score 0):

Each time a key is pressed within the form it checks which key (based on the ASCII table. If the key is a carriage return (ASCII character 13) it calls the validate() method.

I'm not sure if the form tag supports the onkeypress event though

Comment: Key codes are, in some sense, based on ASCII but they are different. So might as use a [key code table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values).  That way no one will be misdirected from the character set and encoding used by JavaScript: Unicode/UTF-16.